# What is the meaning of the "local data frame" message from `dplyr:::print.tbl_df`?

Tags: r, printing, dplyr

When using **dplyr**, the `tbl_df` function prints a statement saying the data frame is "local":

```
> mtcars %>%
+     group_by(gear) 
Source: local data frame [32 x 11]
Groups: gear

    mpg cyl  ...
1  21.0   6  ...
```

I thought a local data frame meant in-memory, and a non-local data frame was a database like SQL. I think I'm wrong in that assumption, though. In this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mh1PqfsXVI&t=1520) at approximately 25:25, Kevin Markham says that `data.frame` objects are not local data frames, which I believed they were.

I looked through the `tbl_df` documentation and used a search function in the [dplyr introduction vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), but can't find a description of a local data frame.

**Question:** ***What is a local data frame?***

Comment: It's just distinguishing it from a remote data source like a MySQL database or something.

Comment: If the linked video is accurate, `data_frame` objects are local data frames, but `data.frame` objects aren't. Now I'm confused too.

Comment: I don't think @Tyler is wrong in original assumption, and there are some semantics at work. Perhaps, consistent with docs and Kevin Markham's statement, one could say a "local data frame" is the data wrapped by tbl_df created from a data.frame, which is not itself a 'local data frame' until wrapped?

Comment: Some insights after digging the source: `print.tbl_df` always prints `cat("Source: local data frame", ...)`, so in this sense any data frame is _local_ ([link1](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/9eb26fcd9076eb36ebb378a218c66294113d4318/R/tbl-df.r)); _local data frame_ is the "opposite" of _remote data source_ ([link2](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/99ddf6fca6a24b31e02b3f402df13c9e5c82f14e/man/copy_to.Rd)).

Comment: @hadley would it be ok to raise an enhance asking for it to be removed, or only printed if verbose==TRUE? I also dislike automatically printing the dimensions, by default. Typically I only want to see the data of interest.

Comment: @smci it would be fine to open it but I'm not going to implement it because I think the current behaviour is much more useful for most people

Answer (score 9):

I'm the author of the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mh1PqfsXVI) mentioned in the question. Here's a summary of the functions relevant to this discussion:

- `data.frame()` is R's function for creating **regular** data frames.
- `data_frame()` is dplyr's function for creating **local** data frames.
- `tbl_df()` and `as_data_frame()` are dplyr's functions for converting a **regular** data frame (or a list) into a **local** data frame.

So, what is the difference between **regular** and **local** data frames? Very little. A **local** data frame is just a **regular** data frame that has been wrapped with the `tbl_df` class for nicer printing. (The data is still stored in a **regular** data frame "under the hood".)

Specifically, printing a **local** data frame only shows the first 10 rows, and as many columns as can fit on your screen. (You can see an example of this behavior at the top of the [RMarkdown document](http://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial) from my [first dplyr video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWjqLW-u3hc), which precedes the tutorial linked above).

All dplyr functions return a **local** data frame by default, though you can convert it back to a **regular** data frame using the `data.frame()` function. One reason to do that is if you prefer the way that **regular** data frames print, namely that you want to see more rows or more columns. However, dplyr allows you to do this without converting it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

# print a local data frame (10 rows, variable number of columns)
flights

# print 15 rows
print(flights, n = 15)

# print all rows (don't run this, since it has 336,776 rows)
print(flights, n = Inf)

# print all columns
print(flights, width = Inf)
```

dplyr has a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/data_frames.html) about data frames that provides more technical details.

Comment: I originally answered that `tbl_df()` and `as_data_frame()` have slightly different uses. @hadley clarified on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/justmarkham/status/702504719135186944) that they are "basically the same", so I updated my answer.

Comment: There's another difference between regular `data.frame`s and `tbl_df`s apart from printing methods. Quoting from the docs: "[ Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame". That means while `data(mtcars); mtcars[, 1]` returns an atomic vector, `tbl_df(mtcars)[,1]` returns a (local) `data.frame` with 1 column. This subtle difference may cause unexpected behavior if not taken care of. I'd suggest using `[[` to extract single columns when using `tbl_df`s therefore (which will always extract a single vector).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/dplyr/docs/tbl_df

A data frame tbl wraps a local data frame. The main advantage to using a tbl_df over a regular data frame is the printing: tbl objects only print a few rows and all the columns that fit on one screen, providing describing the rest of it as text.

from

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

Locales
Note that for local data frames, the ordering is done in C++ code which does not have access to the local specific ordering usually done in R. This means that strings are ordered as if in the C locale